# LdapCtx cannot be cast to DirContextAdapter

Tags: spring-security

I am running with Spring Security 3.2.9 RELEASE, trying to access AD with SpringSecurityLdapTemplate, while encountered this problem.

Dependencies are 
spring-security-ldap-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar

Problem details as below:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx cannot be cast to org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:219)

from the code

```
try {
        while (resultsEnum.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = resultsEnum.next();
            DirContextAdapter dca = (DirContextAdapter) searchResult.getObject();
            Assert.notNull(dca, "No object returned by search, DirContext is not correctly configured");

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Found DN: " + dca.getDn());
            }
            results.add(dca);
        }
    } catch (PartialResultException e) {
        LdapUtils.closeEnumeration(resultsEnum);
        logger.info("Ignoring PartialResultException");
    }
```

Seems it is trying to cast the search result to DirContextAdapter, don't know why it cannot cast.

All my code is running fine with spring-security-3.1.0 Release, because 3.1.0 using different logic

```
 try {
        while (resultsEnum.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = resultsEnum.next();
            // Work out the DN of the matched entry
            DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName(new CompositeName(searchResult.getName()));

            if (base.length() > 0) {
                dn.prepend(searchBaseDn);
            }

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Found DN: " + dn);
            }
            results.add(new DirContextAdapter(searchResult.getAttributes(), dn, ctxBaseDn));
        }
    } catch (PartialResultException e) {
        LdapUtils.closeEnumeration(resultsEnum);
        logger.info("Ignoring PartialResultException");
    }
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After go thought the code, finally found the answer, I was customized the AuthenticationProvider, after spring security 3.2, need add Context.OBJECT_FACTORIES when create DirContext

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, bindUrl);
     env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
     env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
     env.put(Context.OBJECT_FACTORIES, DefaultDirObjectFactory.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to resolve the exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx cannot be cast to org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:345)
```

within an **OSGi** environment (e.g. [apache-karaf](/questions/tagged/apache-karaf) server) an additional package import for `org.springframework.ldap.core.support` is necessary to be added to the manifest of the bundle creating the thread accessing the [spring-ldap](/questions/tagged/spring-ldap) library.
This works for [spring-framework](/questions/tagged/spring-framework) `4.3.14.RELEASE` and [spring-ldap](/questions/tagged/spring-ldap) `2.3.2.RELEASE`. The [spring-framework](/questions/tagged/spring-framework) version `3.x` seems not to require this additional import.

Comment: It should be noted that the `Package-Import` statement for `org.springframework.ldap.core.support` should be added to the bundle from which the thread that executes the LDAP code originates. For example, if a web bundle makes a call to another bundle, which in turn calls the LDAP code, the web bundle will need to add this import.

Comment: @JustinAlbano you are right. I edited my post accordingly to clarify the statement. Thank you very much!